# How can I use the prevState in a state with multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

You see, at this moment I am developing a `showMorePost` that I had previously done successfully, but this time I reformulated it by joining all the states that I had in one with several arguments

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    postsToShow: [],
    hover: false,
    count: 1
  });
  const loopThroughPosts = (count) => {
    for (
      let i = count * postsPerPage - postsPerPage;
      i < postsPerPage * count;
      i++
    ) {
      if (posts[i] !== undefined) {
        arrayForHoldingPosts.push(posts[i]);
      }
    }
    setState({
      ...state,
      postsToShow: arrayForHoldingPosts
    });
  };
  // load the first set of posts when the page loads
  // and then set the value of count to 2
  useEffect(() => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      count: prevState + 1
    }));
    loopThroughPosts(state.count);
  }, []);

  const handleShowMorePosts = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      count: prevState + 1
    }));
    loopThroughPosts(state.count);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Posts postsToRender={state.postsToShow} />
      <button
        onClick={handleShowMorePosts}
        onMouseEnter={() =>
          setState({
            ...state,
            hover: true
          })
        }
        onMouseLeave={() =>
          setState({
            ...state,
            hover: false
          })
        }
      >
        Load more
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The problem is that now instead of bringing me the posts that follow when calling the `handleShowMorePosts`, it generates an infinite loop in which, every time I call the function, it repeats the first three posts.

Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-dust-pybbe?file=/src/App.js:193-2128

Comment: Very complicated implementation for just iterating posts. In 5 - 10 mins I will prepare something much simpler and will work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that will help [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/load-more-hooks-forked-ky4xr?file=/src/App.js).
As a form of appreciation, please mark it as useful.

PS. I am not sure why do you need info about the hover, but I did not remove it.

Comment: No era la solucion que estaba buscando, sin embargo, me gusta mas esta forma que hiciste tu, se ve mas simple, manejable y rapida de hacer y procesar! TY

Comment: That's why StackOverflow exists. We should not just return the answer to your question. Many less experienced developers are asking the questions and they usually do not know that a better solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      count: prevState + 1
    }));
```

should be

```
setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      count: prevState.count + 1
    }));
```

As it’s currently written you’re adding `prevState` (an object) to `1` (an integer) which is why you’re seeing some strange behavior.

### Addition

After a closer look…you also have a race condition where you’re setting state using a callback (the one mentioned above) and then almost immediately setting state again in the `loopThroughPosts` function. That second time of setting the state is essentially keeping the value of `count` at `1`, which can be seen by logging that value to the console. I would recommend splitting up the state like you originally had it to keep your updates to `count` and `postsToShow` separate from each other. If you have a definite reason to have the stage together your component will require some refactoring.

Comment: Just a side note…I prefer to keep pieces of state separate. I find it easier to read and maintain. This implementation above was much more common with class components, when that wasn’t really an option. There’s nothing wrong with splitting it up into multiple pieces of state, each using its own `useState` hook

Comment: It seems quite logical, but unfortunately it continues generating the same bug, and repeats the same three posts

Comment: Thanks for the update, just played with the sandbox a bit and added to the answer. If there’s a reason to keep the state combined I can take a look at some ways to refactor.

Comment: In the end I ended up transforming the component to the solution that @KrystianSztadhaus attached, but I really appreciate that you have taken the time to help me find the solution to the problem